# How to redirect https to http with .htacces file in php

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https, connection

[See error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jURGj.png)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}][1]

OR

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I tried all above code in .htaccess file with https condition on and off also but still getting same error which is Your connection is not private Attackers might be trying to steal your information from ..... I don't want this message I want to direct redirect non-secure which is http because I don't have SSL certificate. Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

You *can not* redirect me from HTTPS to HTTP, if my browser refuses to even create the secure connection to your server in the first place.

What you want here, is simply technically impossible to begin with.

If you want to be able to handle HTTPS requests to your domain in *any* way - then you need to get a valid SSL certificate first of all.

Answer (score 0):

The message you get when you connect to the website is just a default message that tells you that it's not secure, it doesn't show everytime on every computer.
But when you have an unsecure website it will let you know especially when you have the ability to put user information as username and password in, which is really not a good idea, unless it's not for production and just for testing purposes.